# concatenating horizontally in matlab not working

Tags: matlab, concatenation

I have two matrices as A:

```
'1 2 3 4'     0.00959601005678583   4
'1 2 3'        0.00972420458014290  3
'1 2 4'        0.0107007400086486   3
'1 2'          0.0108439251050866   2
```

B:

```
2.20000000000000
1.91335914850010
2.01512388433582
1.73004520013173
```

Why cant i concatenate this horizontally using this function?

C=horzcat(A,B);

The error that shows is:

Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Comment: Are you sure it is two matrices? The first one looks more like a cell array?

Comment: Ya it is so. Actually I need to concatenate these two horizontally..How to do it?

Comment: Is the first one a cell or a matrix? Are the columns to the left in `A` `chars`? What are `A(1)` and `A{1}` and what do you get if you just type `A`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

horzcat(A, B) works when A and B are both matrices, so it won't work here because A is (I am assuming) a cell array.

A cheap way to solve your problem is with a loop that adds values to A:

```
for ii=1:size(A,1)
    A{ii, 4} = B(ii);
end
```

Then your cell A would look like this:

```
A = 
    '1 2 3 4'    [0.0096]    [4]    [2.2000]
    '1 2 3'      [0.0097]    [3]    [1.9134]
    '1 2 4'      [0.0107]    [3]    [2.0151]
    '1 2'        [0.0108]    [2]    [1.7300]
```

Comment: +1 but no need for a loop: `A(:,end+1) = mat2cell(B, ones(1,numel(B)), 1)`